# Rendering vote / up down counts in custom node template drupal up down votes module

Tags: theming, rating

I'm using Voting API and Vote Up / Down module for drupal 6. I'm trying to render the total upvotes - downvotes ( points ) with in the node template.

according to the module readme -

```
<?php
// save the rendered value of the widget
$vud_widget = $node->content['vud_node_widget_display']['#value'];
// avoid show it twice
unset($node->content['vud_node_widget_display']);

// render each value inside $content
print $node->content['body']['#value'];

// print vud widget, here is the place where we want to show it
print $vud_widget;
```

But its returning the whole custom widget template as a string. also the widget is getting rendered two times.

any thoughts ?